# Float values in java

Tags: java

I have some float values in which i do some multiplication

However, the result is a -0, which I found out that the value is too small, hence converted to this answer.

I need to compare the different results which are of float, hence if its -0, I cannot do comparsion.

How can I resolve this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this link on the same topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386596/float-greater-or-less-than-zero

Answer (score 3):

Try and use BigDecimal,

javadocs are here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using double, which will give more precision.  If that still isn't sufficient, you can use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use java.math.BigDecimal. The doc is right here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html